# Dynamic table with controls

Tags: jquery

Am new to Jquery.I have one doubt to do this following Scenario.I create one button.
if I click the button I need to create dynamic table within div.
that dynamic table will contain the

> 1. Textbox(3)
> 2. Dropdown(3)

within the tr,td.Need to add row by row based on button click.
    how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JQUERY SAMPLES</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inputId").click(function () {
                var table = $(this).closest('table');
                if (table.find('input:text').length < 7) {
                    table.append('<tr><td style="width:200px;" align="right">Name <td> <input type="text" id="current Name" value="" /> </td></tr>');
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
     <input type="button" id="inputId" value="ADD"/>
     <div id="sss"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show more code (html/javascript)

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have no table in your html try this,

```
<table>
     <tr><td><input type="button" id="inputId" value="ADD"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Sm4WQ/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample example on how to create a table row with 3 columns dynamically:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="inputId">Click me

<table id="mytable"></table>
```

JS:

```
$("#inputId").click(function () {
    var table = $('table#mytable');
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    var col = $('<td style="width:200px;" align="right"></td>');
    var text = $('<span>Hello</span>');
    var input = $('<input type="text">');
    var dropdown = $('<select></select>');
    row.append(col.clone().append(text));
    row.append(col.clone().append(input));
    row.append(col.clone().append(dropdown));
    table.append(row);
});
```

Hopefully you could mix-match the columns based on your needs.

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R3Hj/8/)